# How to dynamically put a text from textbox to a label inside div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this Viewbag

```
<div id="amount"><h4>@ViewBag.Amount</h4></div>
```

How to I change the amount using jquery? I have this textbox

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAmount" name="txtAmount" placeholder="Enter Amount" data-val="true" data-val-required="Amount to pay is required." data-val-number="Amount to pay must be a number.">
```

I have tried this code but it's not working

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {  $("amount").text(txtAmount); }
```

Comment: I'd suggest abandoning JQuery and using ReactJS, with it's virtualDOM support it should make things much easier for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#amount").children('h4').eq(0).text($('#txtAmount').val());
```

please note though the above will not display as your submit button will submit your form.  If you just want to update the value, you need to prevent the form submitting:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#amount").children('h4').eq(0).text($('#txtAmount').val());
});
```

Also, it looks as if you are using the `h4` for styling purposes - don't do this. Heading tags are for headings only.  Use css to style the `div` tag

Comment: I would, but I can't. says I need more reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {   
             $("#amount>h4").text($('#txtAmount').val());
     });
```

Answer (score -1):

you are missing `#` in following `statement`

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {  $("amount").text(txtAmount); }
```

it should be

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {  $("#amount").text(txtAmount); }
```

Comment: You've also missed the fact the text is also in a h4 and txtAmount is an input so you need to get that val too

Comment: @ Pete read the answer carefully my point was `#` is missing in `$("amount")`

Comment: @ Pete  also he dost mentioned what `txtAmount` is it could be some variable `having string value`.

Comment: I've read the answer carefully, you should read the question more carefully and you will see all the points I have made are pertinent.  If the OP used your answer (and `txtAmount` was indeed a variable - which I don't think it is as why would you call a variable the same thing as the textbox unless it was the textbox object) at the very least they would lose the formatting of the h4 so your answer is still only half correct